# Keyboard not working when plugging to AC adapter

Tags: keyboard, laptop, adapter, 21.10, typing-break

I recently installed Ubuntu in my laptop. It was ran perfectly with my wireless keyboard and mouse.

Yesterday, I replaced my wireless keyboard because some keys stopped working and bought a Dell wired keyboard. I connected and tried it with my laptop. It was working fine, but after two minutes, it started stuttering and all keys automatically get typed!

I thought it is keyboard's fault. So I replaced that keyboard with an HP keyboard, but the same problem occurred. However when I unplugged my AC adapter from my laptop, it worked fine. When I re-plugged in the adapter, the problem re-appeared.

How can I fix this so my keyboard works when plugged into power?

Comment: You can enter to your laptop's "BIOS" setup, go to a place where you can type something and see if this problem occurs there too. If so, it is a hardware problem...